# Splash Screen using webservice

Tags: iphone, dynamic-splash-screen

I have to display a splash screen which resides on a server. Using a web service, I have to get it displayed in my SplashScreenViewController. So it's obvious that when my app launches, it will display a blank screen (img is being downloaded) and after a few seconds, it will show my splash screen.

I know that the splash screen image should have to be in the main bundle, and locally it should be seen as a splash image. But the client wants us to get it loaded from a server.

So can I use an activity indicator in that duration until my splash screen gets loaded?

Answer (score 1):

That is a very bad implementation of a splash screen, but there are no other ways, you will need to use an indicator view, until the image has been downloaded,

Also consider to add a default image its much better than a white view

You will have to deal with some issues, like what would you do if internet connection is very slow or you are not connected, and what would you do if you dont recieve the image you asked for any reason

Comment: Yes you are right, but I am helpless , I hv to do this as Client wants, I am going to talk with him about this issue , and will suggest about this ..

Comment: please note that if your application hangs for some time to show a splash screen, apple may reject it, splash screens are not preferred by apple testing teams.